# Trying to return user to scanner to re enter a number if value falls out of range (<25)

Tags: java, loops

Im trying to configure my code to tell the user to re enter a number, taking them back to the scanner if it falls outside of my specified range of 25

```java
long number;// declares variables for storing number
long factorial = 1;// declare variable for storing factorial

System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 25"); // tells user to enter number
number = scanner.nextLong();


if (number <0)  
    
 System.out.println("Positive numbers only");// if number entered is negative

else if (number > 25)
    
    System.out.println("Number to large to print");
    

else if (number <= 1)// if number entered is 0 or 1 
    System.out.printf("The factorial of " + number+ " is equal to " + factorial);
else {
  // if user enter 10, counter starts at 10 and runs to two
    for(long mynumber = number; mynumber >= 1; mynumber--) {
        factorial = factorial*mynumber; // mynumber would contain different values and that is multiplied by value present in factorial value and storing again in factorial variable
    }

System.out.println("The factorial of " + number +" is equal to " + factorial);
}
```

Comment: You tagged the question with `loops`, so it seems you already know that will be part of the solution. How about `long number = -1; while (number < 0 || number > 25) { System.out.print ("Enter a number ` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean correctInputn = false;

while(!correctInputn)
{
  long number;// declares variables for storing number
  long factorial = 1;// declare variable for storing factorial
    

  System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 25"); // tells user to enter number
  number = scanner.nextLong();
    
  if (number <0) {
    System.out.println("Positive numbers only"); // if number entered is negative
    correctInputn = false;
    continue; // if user enters number less than 0 loops back to code start
  } else if (number > 25) {
    System.out.println("Number to large to print");
    correctInputn = false;
    continue; // if user enters number over 25 loops back to code start
  } else  {
    // if user enter 10, counter starts at 10 and runs to two
    for(long mynumber = number; mynumber >= 1; mynumber--) {
      factorial = factorial * mynumber; // mynumber would contain different values and that is multiplied by value present in factorial value and stored again in factorial variable
    }
    
    System.out.println("The factorial of " + number +" is equal to " + factorial);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the logic, you could extract it to the separate method. The logic itself is pretty strightforward:

- in loop
- ask a number
- check if the number within the bounds
- if not repeate or return if yes

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = getNumberWithin(scan, 1, 25);
}

private static int getNumberWithin(Scanner scan, int lo, int hi) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.format("Enter a number between %d and %d: ", lo, hi);
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        if (num >= lo && num <= hi)
            return num;

        System.err.format("The number should be between %d and %d\n", lo, hi);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```